# Multiple .NET Clients SignalR from different machines

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr.client

I have a SignalR Hub inside an ASP.NET MVC project deployed on a IIS.

I have a WinForms Application running on the same server (App1) using "SignalR .NET Client".

On the client side, I have another WinForms application (App2) that connects to the same hub (With "SignalR .NET Client) using a local network.

The issues appears on App2 while App1 is opened because App2 doesn't connect to the hub. (It stops execution running this code on App 2):

```
//Start connection
await Config.hubConn.Start().ContinueWith(t =>
{
    if (t.IsFaulted)
    {
        Config.logReference.Func_WriteEventInLogFile(DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime(), enum_EventTypes.Error, String.Format("{0}.{1}()", MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.FullName, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name),
                "Connecting to hub: Ko", string.Format("Error connecting to hub with url: {0}", Config.sSignalRHost));
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        Config.logReference.Func_WriteEventInLogFile(DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime(), enum_EventTypes.Debug, String.Format("{0}.{1}()", MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.FullName, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name),
                        "Before invoke App Opened", "Before invoke App Opened");
        Config.hubProxy.Invoke("AppOpened").Wait();
        Config.logReference.Func_WriteEventInLogFile(DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime(), enum_EventTypes.Info, String.Format("{0}.{1}()", MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.FullName, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name),
                        "Connecting to hub: Ok", string.Format("Connection stablished to hub with url: {0}", Config.sSignalRHost));
        return true;
    }
});
```

If I close App1 on server, App2 starts working and is able to connect to hub, but I need both apps running at the same time and connected to hub.

Edited: I think the issue is related to Windows 10 Home Edition IIS (Enabled in “Program and Features”) limits. I am not able to connect 3 SignalR at the same time.

Comment: This might well be the consequence of the limitations imposed by Microsoft on that edition. As per licensing you need profesdional edition for development. That has no such limitations.